# How to get text from angular attributes in selenium?

Tags: selenium

[image]

I want to get the text of attribute value "**downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)**".
Is there any way to do it in selenium?

```
<span class="wrapped-text">
99 
<a class="blue" title="" data-original-title="Download" data-placement="bottom" rel="tooltip" ng-click="downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)">
</span>
```

See the image for tag reference
Thanks

Comment: you want to fetch 99 ?

Comment: @cruisepandey No. i want the value of "downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)"

Comment: downloadBatch() seems like a function. Do you want to take scope of angular element.

Comment: @ketulmodi What do you mean by _...text of attribute value "downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)"..._? Which text exactly? Once you clarify the question reply to the contributor who have _Closed_ the discussion appending the `@` character so that he/she is being notified about the question update and the question can be reopened for canonical answers.

Comment: @DebanjanB  i want the value of function downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)

Answer (score 0):

That is called attribute value, Selenium Provide facility to get the value using `getAttribute`.

**Code** :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-original-title='Download']")).getAttribute("ng-click")
```

It would return a String, Same you can store it and print it.

Comment: He wants to get the value from the function :)

Comment: @Infern0 : then just extract the string starting from ( and ends at , using your binding language.

Comment: let me clarify, (i think) he want to execute the function from attribute value ex: downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0) and get the value return from that function.

Comment: @Infern0 : Not sure.. Let him get back to us.

Comment: @Infern0 Yes you are right i want the value of function downloadBatch(studentPreregisterBatch.batchId,0)